# Import Hex file with leading zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I exported a Hex file but the leading zeros are gone. How can I make them come back

I have this originally this:

```
   A    B   C
0  89   02  FC
1  89   02  FC
2  89   02  FC
```

When exported it became like this:

```
   A    B   C
0  89   2   FC
1  89   2   FC
2  89   2   FC
```

I tried this:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>3}'.format(x))
```

But I am getting this:

```
 A       C      C
0 89    02.0    FC
1 89    02.0    FC
2 89    02.0    FC
```

How can I export it and let it stay as Hex or ad leading zeros without been a float? (Leading zeros in position)?

Comment: Use `df['B'] = df['B'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: '{0:0>2}'.format(x))`

Comment: Or `df['B'] = df['B'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)`

Comment: @jezrael  Thanks for your fast reply. 

 Nope. I tried that also. In both cases, I get 2.0 instead of 02.

Comment: i think there are floats, try `df['B'] = df['B'].astype(int).astype(str).apply(lambda x: '{0:0>2}'.format(x))` if not working  because missing values `df['B'] = df['B'].astype('Int64').astype(str).apply(lambda x: '{0:0>2}'.format(x))`

Comment: Exactly. 

@jezrael

 Actually, you are right, I search a bit more and found the floats problem. I solved differently but you answer is right as well and saves some lines of code. Thanks :)